# Making MouseListener itself change what object he's listening to

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jlabel, mouselistener

I have a game frame, with an array of JLabels in it, that i added existing (extended) MouseListener for two of them (the last and the first) at start. Now, every time a JLabel with a MouseListener had been clicked, i want it "not have" that MouseListener anymore, and instead, the MouseListener goes to the next/previous index in the JLabel array.

I can't find a mechanism that can handle that algorithm.

```
public class NumberGameFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    ...
    JLabels[] numbers;
    int left, right;
    public void playPVC() {
        ...
        left = 0; right = numbers.legth - 1;
        PVCMouse pvc_mouse = new PVCMouse(); // MouseListener
        setPlaybleNumbers(left,right,pvc_mouse);
        ...
    }

    public void setPlaybleNumbers(int left, int right, MouseListener mouse){
        for(int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++){ // "kill" other numbers first
            if (i != left && i != right){
                if (numbers[i].getMouseListeners() != null){
                    numbers[i].removeMouseListener(mouse);
                }
               ...
            }
        }
        numbers[left].addMouseListener(mouse);
        ...
        numbers[right].addMouseListener(mouse);
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

My thought was that some how pvc_mouse.mouseClicked() can invoke this.setPlaybleNumbers(++left,..) or (--right,...), but the MouseListener cant handle the JLabel array and the setPlaybleNumbers method because they are not static.

Comment: well, for better help sooner post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), short, runnable, compilable

Comment: Why not use a single mouse listener attached to the parent panel and maintain an index to the active labels

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see 2 solutions:

1. Make `PVCMouse` inner class of `NumberGameFrame`. It will allow you to use all non static methods and variables.
2. Pass array of labels to `PVCMouse` so it can use it by itself without knowing about `NumberGameFrame`. In this case you'll have to move `left` and `right` variables inside `PVCMouse`.